# What happened to the Mandalorians after Duchess Satine died? Did they go back to being a warrior clan?

Tags: star-wars

Are they still peaceful and subjugated to the Empire or did they go back to their warrior roots? I know that the Death Watch is still a thing in Rebels but they don't represent the population as a whole, are they still the exiled minority or the ruling class of Mandalore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Season 3 and 4 of Rebels feature a fair bit of content set around Mandalore.

It has been subjugated by the Empire and some have joined the empire as elite troops, however it also appears that many aspects of society there have reverted to a more martial tradition:

- Sabine's family (clan Wren) seems to have soldiers/warriors under their command, separate from imperial troops, and her mother and brother are both warriors
- They (Sabine's family and the rebels) later join with outer Mandalorian clans that have their own warriors in opposing the imperial occupation.

It is unclear how much of the population has reverted from the pacifist stance however, but it is clear that many of the traditional elite of Mandalorian society have.